# MongoDB で組合せの生成

Tags: mongodb

配列１[1,2,...,20]と配列２[21,22,..31]があり、配列１から任意の３要素と配列２から任意の２要素(重複なし)を取り出して,要素長＝５（例：[1,2,3,21,22]）の全ての組合せの配列の配列(array of arrays)を作りたい。SQLではネット上に組合せ（重複なし）の例がいくつか見つかりましたが、これをMongoDBで行う場合、どのようなクエリーを書いたらよいのでしょうか？
勿論、できるだけ実行速度が速い方が望ましいです。

Answer (score 1):

MongoDBは、AggregationフレームワークやMap/Reduceフレームワークだけでなく、通常の並べ替えやフィルター機能も持っていますが、（サーバ側のコレクションか配列の）結合には対応していません>。

MongoDBを永続性記憶装置として使用する場合は、クライアント側のアプリケーションで全オブジェクトを読み出し、その順列アルゴリズムを実行してください。

Pythonの例：

```python
import pymongo

from itertools import permutations

dbconn = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
mycoll = dbconn["my_db"]["my_collection"]
doc = mycoll.find_one({"_id": 10001})
#doc["a"] = [1, 3, 5, 7]
#doc["b"] = [2, 4, 6]
aa = []
for ap in permutations(doc["a"], 3):
    for bp in permutations(doc["b"], 2):
        print(ap + bp)
        aa.append(ap + bp)

#(1, 3, 5, 2, 4)
#(1, 3, 5, 2, 6)
#(1, 3, 5, 4, 2)
#.....
#(7, 5, 3, 4, 6)
#(7, 5, 3, 6, 2)
#(7, 5, 3, 6, 4)

print(len(aa))
#144
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。MongoDBの外でやる、ということですね。実際、Node.jsでループ回していますが、MongoDBは素人なので何か方法がないのかと思った次第です。

Comment: はい、この場合MongoDBの外でやるということです。